# Reading data from PostgreSQL backup directory

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, rdbms

Let's say I have a backup directory containing PostgreSQL data from some other system. By default, the data is stored at `/var/lib/postgresql`. After changing the default data directory to the path of the backup directory by editing `/etc/postgresql/<version>/main/postgresql.conf`, I'm able to identify all the users present in the backup PostgreSQL instance. However, I'm unsure how to access the data stored in all the databases and tables for different users without knowing the password for each user. Is there any way to retrieve the data without requiring the password for each user?

I'm able to identify all the users within the backup PostgreSQL instance, but I'm uncertain about how to determine the databases and tables associated with each user and access their respective data.

Comment: 1) Knowing the user passwords is not necessarily going to give you access to the data. The password just allows the user to connect, the privileges granted to the user determine what they can see and/or use once they are connected. 2) Why are you trying this?

Comment: Don't mess up your installation like that. Restore the backup properly. The backup must contain configuration files as well. How was it taken? BTW, this is not a question for Stackoverflow. You could ask on DBA Stackexchange.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Actually I only have access to the data directory, and I've forgotten the password for an important user. So I'm not sure how to retrieve the data.

Comment: Access is no problem. Whoever wants you to solve the problem will give you access.